# how to make the total form fields into two column using Angular and bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I have a angular form inside bootstrap modal and i need all the fields will be devided into two columns but as per my code its not generating the output as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div id="myCouponModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="icon-box">
                            <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
                        </div>              
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Coupons</h4>    
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <!-- div starts -->
                                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="section">
                                            <div class="help-content">
                                                <h5>Coupon code: HOLI123</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-content">
                                                <div class="form-field">
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Rule Name</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Rule Name" #RuleName required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Coupon Code</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Coupon Code" 
                                                        #CouponCode maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" (keyup)="makeCaps($event)" required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Coupon Category</mat-label>
                                                        <select matNativeControl required (change)="getItemsAsPerCategory($event)"  #CouponCategory>
                                                            <option value="">Select Coupon Category</option>
                                                            <option value=Product>Product</option>
                                                            <option value=Store>Store</option>
                                                            <!--<option value=Category>Category</option> -->
                                                        </select>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Coupon Value</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Coupon Value" 
                                                        #CouponValue maxlength="15" pattern="[0-9]+" required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" readonly>
                                                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                                        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Min Cart Value</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Min Cart Value"  
                                                        #maxDisValue maxlength="15" pattern="[0-9]+" required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-field">
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Coupon Type</mat-label>
                                                        <select matNativeControl required  #Type>
                                                            <option value="">Select Coupon Type</option>
                                                            <option value=Flat>Flat</option>
                                                            <option value=percentage>Percentage</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Coupon Count</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Coupon Count" 
                                                        #Count maxlength="15" pattern="[0-9]+" required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Coupon Description</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Coupon Description" #CouponDescription required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>Max Discount Value</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput placeholder="Max Discount Value" 
                                                        #maxDisValue maxlength="15" pattern="[0-9]+" required>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                        <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
                                                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" readonly>
                                                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                                        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <!-- div starts -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteProductItem()">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here I have some fields with section header and as per this code its coming like the below image.

[image]

Here all fields are coming in same column. I need the section header should place left and in right section all the fields will be divided into two columns.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split your form in two columns

```
 div class = row
   div class col-md-6
     your left fields
   div class col-md-6
     your rights fields
```